# .net core can't open file from python script

Tags: c#, python, .net, asp.net-core

Someone i know has made a python script that checks validity of some files. Right now that only works local, but he wants it to work cloud based. He gave me the .exe file with a few other files that i can use. I'm using .net core 2 for my backend. I can start the .exe file just fine. But when the python code tries to open the config file he made, the program returns it cannot find the file.

```
try:
    json_data=open('config.txt').read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    sys.exit('FATAL ERROR: config.txt not found!') <--returns this
except Exception as e:
    sys.exit('FATAL ERROR: {}'.format(e))
```

The file is in the same folder as the .exe. Whenever i just run it straight from windows it works perfect and it can find the file. But whenever i run the program from within my .net core webapp it gives back that error. I'm using visual studio 2017 for development and debugging.

Here is my c# code i got from a post on stackoverflow to run the exe:

```
public IActionResult Index(string cmd, string args)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = "Python\\Windows 64-bit\\mdqt.exe";                
            start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", cmd, args);
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.CreateNoWindow = false; 
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            start.RedirectStandardError = true; 
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                string result = "";
                while (!process.HasExited)
                {
                    while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                    {
                         result += process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    }
                    while (!process.StandardError.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        result += process.StandardError.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                return Ok(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok(e);
        }
    }
```

Could it be some file permissions issue? If so how can i fix it?

**EDIT:**

I have set the working directory using the following code:

```
start.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath.ToString(), "Python\\Windows 64-bit");
```

It now gives me an error it cannot find the folder. Yet when I put the link into the filemanager(and ofcourse delete 1 backslash everywhere), it directs me to the right folder. Could this be a permissions issue? The folder I'm linking to is within the project folder, so IIS should be able to reach that folder as it has permission to interact with the parent folders. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Set [WorkingDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2) to the folder containing that 'config.txt'

Comment: within the c# code or the python code?

Comment: The C# code. The link I gave you is for the `ProcessStartInfo` .NET class, which you use on the 5th line of your C# class.